# run a batch script as differend user inside Powershell script

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a powershell script and from inside this, i want to run a batch script as differend user.
That means i have a AD service user account and with this i must run the batch script.
It must work like a scheduled task in windows, where you can run it as differend user without store the password.

Now the question is how i can run the batch script from inside a powershell script with the service user and don't need to store the password in the Powershell script?

i have tried this:

```
Start-Process -Credentil "Domain\Account" -FilePath "CMD.exe" -Argumentlist "/c C:\myScript.cmd"
```

The result is that a window pops up where i must typ in the password for the service user.

Can any one help me with this?

Thank you and best regards,
Nico

Answer (score 1):

You need to register system scheduler task with credentials or store password in the script:

```
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))
Start-Process -Credential $credentials -FilePath "cmd.exe"
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your fast answer. With "you need to register system scheduled task" you mean i must create a scheduled task via the GUI of windows for scheduled tasks? My problem is, that it is not allowed to store the password for the AD service account inside the script as plain text.

Comment: You can register task from UI or from PowerShell (there is a tutorial http://duffney.io/Create-ScheduledTasks-SecurePassword). But what is important you need register it for specified user.